# set mapView.delegate with Google Maps iOS SDK 1.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I just updated from Google Maps iOS SDK 1.3.1 to 1.4 and now my app crashes when I set the delegate like `mapView_.delegate = self`. If I delete this line my delegate methods are not called.
How can I set the delegate in v 1.4?
Thanks

Comment: What does the error for the crash say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you have added the googlemaps framework and bundle correctly. Ensure your header file has

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController<GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

In your implementation file ensure that you set the delegate only after initialising your mapView_. That is below order should be followed:

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks, `<GMSMapViewDelegate>` was missing

Answer (score 0):

In 1.4 there are new delegate methods. Make sure you implement the required ones.

The two new methods in 1.4 are

- `mapView:willMove:` and
- `mapView:idleAtCameraPosition:`

Comment: I've got: `- (void) mapView: (GMSMapView *) mapView willMove:(BOOL)gesture`, `- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *) mapView didTapMarker:(GMSMarker *)marker` and `- (void) mapView: (GMSMapView *) mapView idleAtCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position`. None gets called.