# Make GMSCircle respond to tap?

Tags: ios, delegates, touch, listener, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the Google Maps API for iOS and I want to make it so when you tap on a GMSCircle it pops up a little thing I coded elsewhere. I have set the circle to "tappable" but I cannot find what I need to set or make to listen for the tap. What do I use?

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D circleCenter = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10,10);
GMSCircle *circ = [GMSCircle circleWithPosition:circleCenter
                                         radius:10];
circ.tappable = true;
[circ setFillColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.5]];

circ.map = mapView_;
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to use the delegate method [didTapOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p#a3a2bf2ff4481528f931183cb364c0f4b) :

```
- (void) mapView: (GMSMapView *) mapView  didTapOverlay: (GMSOverlay *) overlay
```

Here the parameter overlay indicates the overlay that was tapped. So you need to check if it equals circ.

**EDIT** : Adding details on how to check for circle within didTapOverlay

When `GMSCircle` is added to the map, a corresponding `GMSPolygon` is also created. If the circle is set as tappable, then on tapping it, the overlay passed to the `didTapOverlay` method is this related polygon and not the circle . So a direct comparison between the overlay and the circle is not possible. Hence as Raspu as pointed out, you can set a value in title using `circ.title =` and then inside didTapOverlay, you can check if `overlay.title` is same as `circ.title`. This works because the title property of the circle is within the corresponding polygon and hence will be present in the overlay parameter.

Comment: Thanks! How do I check if its equal to circ? I have tried if([overlay isEqual:circ]) and if(overlay == circ), each to no avail

Comment: I had the same problem, It seems that for circles the google maps renders a polygon. I used overlay.title to save an identifier.

Comment: Actually it turns out none of the delegate methods are being called. I  have the mapview_'s delegate set to self and the delegate set in the header. Help?

Comment: I have updated the answer on how to identify if the circle was tapped. Thanks to @Raspu for pointing this out. redlago, for delegate methods not getting called , check if this [earlier post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877202/set-mapview-delegate-with-google-maps-ios-sdk-1-4/17878564#17878564) helps.

Comment: @redIago can you please show us the code where you are creating the map.

Comment: Please star here if you think this is a bug.
https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6890