# I want to give delegates to circles on GoogleMap and transition to another ViewController in segue

Tags: swift, google-maps

**problem**

I want to make the screen transition when I tap a circle drawn using GMSCircle, not a marker or title.
I wrote the code below, but tapping the circle does not show anything in the debug area and I can not transition.
What is missing?

**environment**
swift4
Google Maps SDK for iOS
Xcode 9.4.1

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMaps
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, GMSMapViewDelegate{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        // map
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 35.687396, longitude: 139.743924, zoom: 17)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.delegate = self
        self.view = mapView
        // mapView.isMyLocationEnabled

        let circle = GMSCircle()
        circle.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(35.687396, 139.743924)
        circle.radius = CLLocationDistance(10)
        circle.fillColor = UIColor.blue
        circle.isTappable = true
        circle.map = mapView
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTapCircle: GMSCircle) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goTalk", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm really sorry

Comment: Edited to improve the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked what was happening and I noticed that as you said, it didn't work.
[But according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975273/make-gmscircle-respond-to-tap), I noticed that you need this other delegate method:

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap overlay: GMSOverlay) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goTalk", sender: nil)
    }
```

This works propertly.

Comment: It went well
I thank you. As a matter of fact, I could not solve this problem for more than two weeks